# Importing JSON to HTML with Angular.JS (error)!

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I'm having issues transferring my JSON data to HTML with Angular.JS, I'm doing a programming course and this is an issue I came across that the author doesn't seem to have, can anyone help?

I linked angular correctly, I added the app correctly, it should work, any ideas?

https://pastebin.com/K4HR23Tk - HTML

```
<html ng-app="myQuiz">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test Your Knowledge: Saturn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quiz.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="myQuiz" ng-controller="QuizController">
<h1>Test Your Knowledge: <span>Saturn</span></h1>
<div class="progress"> {{totalQuestions}} </div>
```

https://pastebin.com/5emA4016 - JS

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myQuiz',[]); 
    app.controller('QuizController',['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope,$http,$sce){ 
        $scope.score = 0;
        $scope.activeQuestion = -1;
        $scope.activeQuestionAnswered = 0;
        $scope.percentage = 0;
        $http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
            $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
            $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Use jsfiddle or codepen to share your code. They can link angular JS by choosing it as an option.

Comment: Ok, I will try to put my code in that right now so I can get some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a **closing square bracket** `]`. This is the completed code:

```js
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myQuiz',[]); 
    app.controller('QuizController',['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope,$http,$sce){ 
        $scope.score = 0;
        $scope.activeQuestion = -1;
        $scope.activeQuestionAnswered = 0;
        $scope.percentage = 0;
        $http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
            $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
            $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;
        }).catch(function(response){
            console.error(response && response.message || response);
            console.log("Using 2 dummy questions");
            $scope.myQuestions = ["dummy", "questions"];
            $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;
        });
    // below inserted the missing `]`.
    }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myQuiz">
<body ng-controller="QuizController">
  <div>Total questions: {{totalQuestions}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="question in myQuestions">{{question}}</div>
```

Your opening `[` after `'QuizController'` never got closed by a matching `]`.

This mistake could be avoided if you use a decent editor or linter that can help highlight or automatically close each block for you.

**An extra advice to you from someone who's been there** (I assume you were a beginner since you mentioned "paste" in your comment and you did claim you were taking a programming course) -- If you're struggling over this simple typo, it means that you're going too fast and do not stop to digest.
Take it slow and read everything thoroughly and try to understand it. Do not fall into copy and pasting code trap. It could take you much more time to learn and write good code.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work as it removed the {{totalQuestions}} but is not showing "5" as total questions yet. I'll play around with it, thanks for the advice. Yes I am new to Angular JS but I've been doing HTML and Swift for a while now! Really appreciate the help :D I think I know what to do now <3

Comment: Try initialing `$scope.totalQuestions = 0` before the `$http.get` block. If your HTML shows `0` then it's probably because it's not bound correctly to update the value once the promise is resolved.

Comment: You can show your love by voting both answers and mark either as the correct one.

Comment: Oh non, does this mean @user9286154 is incapable of love? :o(

Answer (score 0):

Add closing square bracket }]);

You opend array here ['$scope

Comment: I will try this! where should I paste this exactly? Thanks for the help :D <3

Comment: Second line from the bottom

Comment: The missing `]` should be used to closed the `app.controller` block. Try using an IDE with autocomplete or block highlighting. It should help you with closing brackets.

Comment: This did not help my issue, it still says {{totalQuestions}} and not importing my data. Thanks though :D

Comment: @PieOhPah I will try to add the ] and see what happens. thanks.

Comment: @PieOhPah Neither of these things helped me, is there maybe a way you can guide me to show exactly where the "]" or }]; will go? I still keep getting {{totalQuestions}} on my index html.

Comment: I am very confused. I tried adding either "]" and "}];" in various places, I thought I already had enough and doing this never made a change in loading my json.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer but contains tips on how to avoid errors which the OP encountered.

Always start with the absolute minimum code, then build it up, always making sure the code keeps working as you add complexity. Whenever it breaks, it was obviously something you just added/changed.

In the following code examples I removed the need for the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and added `"use strict"` to activate [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) which I always recommend. Click on the `Run code snippet` buttons to see the code in action:

```js
angular.module('myQuiz',[]);
angular.module('myQuiz').controller('QuizController', function(){
  "use strict";
  console.log("QuizController");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myQuiz">
<div ng-controller="QuizController">
```

Injecting dependencies with array syntax (I think it's a good idea to format the dependencies on a separate line):

```js
angular.module('myQuiz',[]);
angular.module('myQuiz').controller('QuizController', [
    '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http){ 
        "use strict";
        console.log("Injected $scope successfully?:", Boolean($scope));
        console.log("Injected $http successfully?:", Boolean($http));
    }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myQuiz">
<div ng-controller="QuizController">
```

Then try to access external data. This example provokes an error. I'll let you run the code to see why:

```js
angular.module('myQuiz',[]);
angular.module('myQuiz').controller('QuizController',[
    '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http){ 
        "use strict";
        $http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
            console.log(quizData.data);
        }).catch(function(response){
            console.error("Unable to load quiz data");
            console.error(response && response.message || response);
        });
    }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myQuiz">
<div ng-controller="QuizController">
```

Comment: @user9286154 All the above examples work without needing JSFiddle or codepen